# Python ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section while MySQLdb connection

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python

conn_file.cfg :

```
[user]
connectString=host="192.xx.xx.xx",user="user",passwd="pw",db="college"
```

db_parser.py

```
import ConfigParser as cp
import MySQLdb as ms

config = cp.ConfigParser()
config.read(r".\conn_file.cfg")
connectString = config.get('user','connectString')
con = ms.connect(connectString)
print(con)
```

Error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "db_parser.py", line 6, in <module>
    connectString = config.get('user','connectString')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 607, in get
    raise NoSectionError(section)
ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'user'
```

Comment: I think you made a mistake, what you want to import is `configparser`  (notice the case difference with `ConfigParser`)

Comment: But its working

Comment: See: https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html . Especially: "The `ConfigParser` module has been renamed to `configparser` in Python 3."

Comment: I find it its path problem